# mplot3d narrow spline surface missing from output

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have setup mplot3d to provide a 3D surface plot per the example.
When I plot my data I am seeing that the surface is missing from a ridge running through the surface (see image). I noticed that surface filling appears to follow the stride but the grid-lines make viewing difficult at lower step sizes.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import cm, pyplot
import numpy

Z = data[-300::]
X,Y = numpy.mgrid[:len(Z), :len(Z[0])]

fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(20, 10), dpi=800)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X,
                       Y,
                       Z,
                       rstride=len(Z)/5, 
                       cstride=len(Z[0])/10, 
                       alpha=.6, 
                       linewidths=(.5,), 
                       antialiased=True, 
                       cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       vmin=124,
                       vmax=186
                       )



cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=130, cmap=cm.coolwarm, vmin=124, vmax=186)

ax.set_xlim(len(Z) * 1.2, 0)
ax.set_ylim(0, len(Z[0]) * 1.2)

ax.elev = 25
ax.azim = 20

cb = fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
```

[image: Plot result]

Is there a way to fill the missing surface?

Answer (score 0):

The only way i have found to accomplish this is by setting the stride to one and linewidth to 0.  The downside to this is that I appear to lose the grid overlay.

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X,
                       Y,
                       Z,
                       shade=True,
                       rstride=1, cstride=1, linewidth=0, 
                       linewidths=(.5,), 
                       antialiased=True, 
                       )
```